# How to switch error Messages in Parsley.js

Tags: javascript, parsley.js

I have written a specific Validator for Parsley.js to determine if a selected Date matches some criteria:

1. Date is between a and b years in the past.
2. If only min-date is given, there should be another message

I have solved this by writing one function and assign it to two validators to be able to translate the messages differently.

Is there any better way to dynamically switch the message based on the parameters given for the validator?

```
// translationkeys:
// timerange: "Muss zwischen %s und %s Jahren in der Vergangenheit liegen"
// mintimerage: "Muss mindestens %s Jahr(e) in der Vergangenheit liegen"

var timeValidator = function (value, req) {
if(req.min){
    var mindate = moment().subtract(req.min, 'y');
}
if(req.max){
    var maxdate = moment().subtract(req.max, 'y');
}

var date = moment(value, 'DD.MM.YYYY');

if( req.max ){
    return ( date.isAfter(maxdate)&& date.isBefore(mindate) );
  } else {
    return ( date.isBefore(mindate) );
}
}

window.ParsleyValidator.addValidator('timerange', timeValidator,
  32
)
window.ParsleyValidator.addValidator('mintimerange', timeValidator,
  32
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: There is no possibility.